# Is having 3 whole eggs at breakfast harmful?

Tags: nutrition, diet, proteins, cholesterol

Last couple of day I have been having 3 whole eggs scrambled with around 2 tea spoon soybean oil in breakfast. Some friends of mine told me having 3 whole eggs is harmful for my health. I understand that it may increase my cholesterol. But in my opinion, eggs are fulled with protein and other important nutrients ( and easy to cook :P ). Do eggs raise cholesterol levels?

Comment: See also: [What health impacts, if any, does consuming a large number of eggs each day have?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16783/41888), [Is eating eggs bad for me?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1186/41888), [How many eggs can one eat per day?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/529/11958)

Comment: Soybean oil is very risky, and likely extremely bad for your health. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/01/200117080827.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The American Heart Association no longer condemns eggs in its guidelines. But it does recommend that people limit themselves to 300 milligrams of cholesterol daily (a single egg has about 200 milligrams of cholesterol, as well as a mix of saturated and unsaturated fats, including the  monounsaturated kind found in olive oil). The federal government, in its Dietary Guidelines for Americans, notes that eating an egg yolk per day “does not result in increased blood cholesterol levels, nor does it increase the risk of cardiovascular disease in healthy people.”
>
> <sup>Source: [New York Times](https://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/11/14/ask-well-how-many-eggs-can-i-eat/)</sup>

But – if your friends eat sugary cereal, bagels etc., their diet is worse than a bit too much cholesterol. Furthermore, if you eat scrambled eggs with bacon, it is probably wiser to cut down the bacon than the eggs…

> Dr. Hu said that eggs are a particularly good replacement for less healthful fare, like processed meats and refined carbohydrates. In fact, studies suggest that for most people, starting your day with a breakfast of scrambled eggs will have a better impact on your overall cholesterol profile than a bagel or a bowl of sugary cereal.
>
> <sup>ibid.</sup>

As **@Jan** pointed out in the comments: There are hyperresponders to cholesterol, [which report cholesterol spikes in the blood after consumption of cholesterol](https://academic.oup.com/jn/article/133/4/1036/4688287). For most humans, [fats play a bigger role in cholesterol levels than cholesterol consumption.](https://www.webmd.com/cholesterol-management/ss/slideshow-cholesterol-overview)

Comment: You probably intended to make a link for your 2nd quote. Also, would you mind to include sometihng about "cholesterol responders?"

Comment: @Jan Note taken. The link is not forgotten, it’s the same source as the first quote (hence ibid)

Comment: I just want to mention that the latest [Dietary Guidelines for Americans 2015-2020](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015/resources/2015-2020_Dietary_Guidelines.pdf) (p. 32) do not recommend limiting cholesterol intake to 300 mg/day or limiting 1 egg per day anymore. But, as said, this may still be important for some people.